# How to insert values into database from textbox and dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql, asp.net

I am not that good at either .net or sql.

The thing is I have a web form and a database. The form would let the user enter information in textbox and dropdownlist. 
the data in the dropdownlist is saved in a table.

So, I am reading values from the table, when the users fill the form and choose from the dropdownlist the options they want, the data in the textbox and selected dropdownlist should be sent back to be saved in the database.

I have successfully read the value from the database and show them in the dropdownlist like in the following code:

```css
 public class state
        {
            public string stateID { get; set; }
            public string stateName { get; set; }
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public static List<state> PopulateDropDownList()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<state> objDept = new List<state>();



            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ****; Initial Catalog = LCF2016; Integrated Security = true");

            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT STATE_ID, STATE_Name FROM state", con))
                 {
                     con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        objDept.Add(new state
                        {
                            stateID = dt.Rows[i]["STATE_ID"].ToString(),
                            stateName = dt.Rows[i]["STATE_Name"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                return objDept;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //url is the path of our web method (Page name/functionname)
                    url: "Default.aspx/PopulateDropDownList",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //called on jquery ajax call success
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#ddlstate').empty();
                         $('#ddlstate').append("<option value='0'>-Select-</option>");
                         $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {

 $("#ddlstate").append($("<option></option>").val(value.stateID).html(value.stateName));
                         });
                    },
                    //called on jquery ajax call failure
                    error: function ajaxError(result) {
                         alert(result.status + ' : ' + result.statusText);
                    }
               });
          });
     </script>﻿



<p>State</p>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" Width="160px" />
```

However, even if I am successfully calling the data to be shown into the dropdownlist, I am not able to insert the selected data along with the data in the textbox back into the database. In other word, the data is not saved into the database.

Here is my code for inserting the data "when click submit":

```css
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
            {
                Label1.Text = ("**Thanks for entering your information");
            }

        }

          protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {

            using (SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ****; Initial Catalog = LCF2016; Integrated Security = true"))
            {
                vid.Open();
                using (SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand("insert into LCF2016 (Fname, Lname, Email, Birthdate, Phone, Address, City, STATE_ID, Zip, Country_ID, Days_Per_Month, Primary_Language, Secondary_Language, Occupation_ID, HearAbout_ID, Other_Skills) Values(@Fname, @Lname, @Email, @Birthdate, @Phone, @Address, @City, @STATE_ID,  @Zip, @Country_ID,  @Days_Per_Month, @Primary_Language, @Secondary_Language, @Occupation_ID, @HearAbout_ID @Other_Skills)", vid))

                {
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", TextBox1.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", TextBox2.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox3.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", TextBox4.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", TextBox5.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", TextBox6.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", TextBox7.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATE_ID", ddlstate.SelectedValue);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", TextBox8.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_ID", ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days_Per_Month", TextBox10.Text);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Primary_Language", ddllangp.SelectedValue);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Secondary_Language", ddllangs.SelectedValue);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation_ID", ddloccup.SelectedValue);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HearAbout_ID", ddlhearabout.SelectedValue);
                    xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Other_Skills", TextBox15.Text);
                    xp.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }
```

The error I get is

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,
by jquery

```
$( "#ddlstate" ).change(function() {
  $('[id*=Hiddenfield1]').attr('value', $( "#ddlstate" ).val());
});
```

body

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="Hiddenfield1" runat="server">
```

code

```
xp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATE_ID", Hiddenfield1.vlue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Never having tried exactly what you are doing here, my best approximation is that the ViewState is invalid when you do your PostBack because you're using Ajax to populate the drop down list. It appears you are populating your drop down list using an Ajax call, then trying to use a full page post to send that data back to the server.You have several things going on here I don't quite understand, but what I would suggest is this.

I think you need to do a server side Request / Post, i.e. bind your drop down list and text box controls server side on the request, and then use the normal postback to send the data back to the server.  OR, use AJAX both ways -receive AND send your data, but not try to mix them as you are.